# How do I delete a Naukri account?

Tags: account-management

I have a Naukri account that, due to some personal concerns, I would like to delete.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The link can be found in the registration mail that you would have recieved from Naukri. Incase you have lost that, please send across a mail to bugs@naukri.com mentioning your username, email etc.

Comment: Are you associated with Naukri?

Comment: No I am not. but I know because I deleted my account yesterday

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to delete the Naukri.com account.
Here are the simple steps:

1. Login into Naukri.com account.
2. Open the link : [Delete Naukri Account](https://login.naukri.com/mnj/delete?&utm_campaign=FTD&utm_medium=mailer&utm_source=WelcomeMailer). If you suspect the above link, please check it manually. There is nothing to worry about.
3. Again enter the password to confirm the deletion of your account.
4. Here you go. Your Account deleted.